# fatfreeframework with SQL Server databse using mapper copyfrom method with partial insert

Tags: sql-server, mapper, fat-free-framework, identity-insert

I am attempting to insert a record using the copyFrom('POST') and save() methods of fatfreeframework v3.5. The data from POST does not contain an id field which for this table is set as an autoincrement. The SQL from the logs is

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [xrefs] ON;

INSERT INTO [xrefs] ([status], [supply_id], [description], [unit], [unitcost], [cap], [rev], [buq]) 
VALUES ('test', 'Htest', 'test', 'test', '1', '1', 1, 1)
```

As you can see fatfree is adding the set identity insert despite the fact there is no id column included in the insert. Is there a way to tell mapper not to set this flag? Or is there another workaround? I could get the current max ID and then insert +1 but that seems clunky.

I should add this SQL fails because the id column is not included in the columns list.

```
$this->db->exec(
            (preg_match('/mssql|dblib|sqlsrv/',$this->engine) &&
            array_intersect(array_keys($pkeys),$ckeys)?
                'SET IDENTITY_INSERT '.$this->table.' ON;':'').
            'INSERT INTO '.$this->table.' ('.$fields.') '.
            'VALUES ('.$values.')',$args
        );
```

This is the code that sets IDENTITY_INSERT in mapper.php function insert.

```
$this->logger->write( 'xrefs schema:'. 
   json_encode( $this->tongpodb->schema( 'xrefs' ) ) );
```

Calling schema on the the db object gives back this array 
{"id":{"type":"int","pdo_type":1,"default":null,"nullable":false,"pkey":true},"changed_date":{"type":"datetime","pdo_type":2,"default":null,"nullable":true,"pkey":false},"status":{"type":"varchar","pdo_type":2,"default":null,"nullable":false,"pkey":false},"supply_id":{"type":"varchar","pdo_type":2,"default":null,"nullable":false,"pkey":true},"description":{"type":"varchar","pdo_type":2,"default":null,"nullable":true,"pkey":false},"unit":{"type":"varchar","pdo_type":2,"default":null,"nullable":false,"pkey":false},"hcpcs":{"type":"char","pdo_type":2,"default":null,"nullable":true,"pkey":false},"unitcost":{"type":"decimal","pdo_type":2,"default":null,"nullable":false,"pkey":false},"cap":{"type":"decimal","pdo_type":2,"default":null,"nullable":false,"pkey":false},"rev":{"type":"smallint","pdo_type":1,"default":null,"nullable":false,"pkey":false},"buq":{"type":"smallint","pdo_type":1,"default":null,"nullable":true,"pkey":false},"create_ts":{"type":"datetime","pdo_type":2,"default":null,"nullable":true,"pkey":false},"log_ts":{"type":"int","pdo_type":1,"default":null,"nullable":true,"pkey":false},"filename":{"type":"varchar","pdo_type":2,"default":null,"nullable":true,"pkey":false},"line_no":{"type":"smallint","pdo_type":1,"default":null,"nullable":true,"pkey":false},"file_ts":{"type":"datetime","pdo_type":2,"default":null,"nullable":true,"pkey":false}}

As you can see id has a "pkey":true entry so one could look at the fields from post then look at this and determine if IDENTITY_INSERT needs to set. Perhaps I will implement this. I worry this is above my paygrade.

Comment: Please report that issue on the framework bug tracker: github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/issues

Comment: I have now done that. So you think this is a bug? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Updated to the latest version of fatfree fixed this issue.